# Merge two sql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I' have two tables sessions and online

session is

```
 |   id   |      time    |
 |    1   |   1413170771 |
 |    2   |   1413174398 |
 |    7   |   1413174567 |
```

online is

```
 |   id   |   username   |   city   |       lat     |     lon     |
 |    1   |     Jon      |  Toronto |   45.4642700  |  9.1895100  |
 |    2   |     Danny    |  Ottawa  |   46.5645600  |  9.3456883  |
 |    7   |     Martin   |  Calgary |   46.6775339  |  9.5469944  |
```

I need to estract all time from session and all online users and order it for distances.

For example if Martin wants to see all online users and distance from him the result must be

```
| id | Users   |  distance |     time   |
|  7 | Martin  |     0     | 1413174567 |
|  1 |  Jon    |    100    | 1413170771 |
|  2 |  Danny  |    250    | 1413174398 |
```

The problem is:

I need to extract Martin lat and lon from online table then calculate the distance, for distance i want Use this query

```
      $R = 3959;
      $lat= ???
      $lon= ????

      SELECT *, (
      $R * acos( cos( radians($lat) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) 
      * cos( radians( lon ) - radians($lon) ) + sin( radians($lat) ) * sin(radians(lat)) ) ) AS distance 
      FROM online
      HAVING distance < $rad 
      ORDER BY distance 
      LIMIT 0 , 20"
```

Comment: Have you check on [PostGIS](http://postgis.net/) project? You will not need to deal with trig functions there...

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres or MySQL? The two are very different

Comment: Mysql but I'm thinking for migration so I hope a solution for both. If it not possible Mysql is preferred

Answer (score 1):

A procedure can do the magic, check this out

```
-- Trigger DDL Statements
DELIMITER //

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS cal_distance;

CREATE PROCEDURE cal_distance (IN var_id INT) 
BEGIN
DECLARE R INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE var_lat DOUBLE DEFAULT 0; -- NOT USED?
DECLARE var_lon DOUBLE DEFAULT 0; -- NOT USED?

--GET lon and lat for John
SELECT lat INTO var_lat, lon INTO var_lon 
FROM online 
WHERE id = var_id;

SELECT *, (
R * acos(cos(radians(var_lat)) * cos(radians(var_lat)) 
 * cos(radians(lon) - radians(var_lon)) + sin(radians(var_lat)) * sin(radians(lat))) ) AS distance 
FROM online LEFT JOIN session
USING (id)
HAVING distance >= 0
ORDER BY distance 
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

To call the procedure

```
CALL cal_distance (1);
```

If you want to avoid prodecures, the try

```
SET @R = 3959;
SET @var_lon = NULL;
SET @var_lat = NULL;

SELECT lat, lon INTO @var_lat, @var_lon
FROM online 
WHERE id = 1;

SELECT *, (
@R * acos( cos( radians(@var_lat) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) 
 * cos( radians( lon ) - radians(@var_lon) ) + sin( radians(@var_lat) ) * sin(radians(lat)) ) ) AS distance 
FROM online LEFT JOIN session
USING (id)
HAVING distance >= 0
ORDER BY distance
```

**[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7a49a/6)**

Just using a subquery, though I won't prefer this way.

```
SELECT *, (
3959* acos( cos( radians(var_lat) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) 
 * cos( radians( lon ) - radians(var_lon) ) + 
sin( radians(var_lat) ) * sin(radians(lat)) ) ) AS distance 
FROM online, (SELECT lat AS var_lat, lon AS var_lon FROM online  WHERE id = 1) AS new_table
HAVING distance >= 0
ORDER BY distance
```

**[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7a49a/15)**

Comment: @alberto: Solved your issue ?

Comment: Thanks @Rokse but I need a query/subquery otherwise it do not work with my db abstraction layer

Comment: @Rokse In the last query there is no connection with session table